# Values in A Range, Same Row, Different Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
With WB2.Sheets("Sheet2")   'Add new book, headers, and formatting
  .Range("A1").Value = "Display Name"
  .Range("B1").Value = "Language"
  .Range("C1").Value = "Locale"
  .Range("D1").Value = "WorkType"
  .Range("E1").Value = "EntryType"
  .Range("F1").Value = "TitleInternalAlias"
  .Range("G1").Value = "TitleDisplayUnlimited"
  .Range("H1").Value = "LicenseRightsDescription"
  .Range("I1").Value = "(License)Type"
  .Range("J1").Value = "FormatProfile"
  .Range("K1").Value = "Start"
  .Range("L1").Value = "End"
  .Range("M1").Value = "Description"
  .Range("N1").Value = "Other Terms"
  .Range("O1").Value = "Other Instructions"
  .Range("P1").Value = "Content ID"
  .Range("Q1").Value = "Product ID"
  .Range("R1").Value = "Metadata"
  .Range("S1").Value = "AltID"
  .Range("T1").Value = "Release History (Original)"
  .Range("U1").Value = "Release History (DVD)"
  .Range("V1").Value = "Rental Duration"
  .Range("W1").Value = "Watch Duration"
  .Range("X1").Value = "WSP"
  .Range("Y1").Value = "Tier"
  .Range("Z1").Value = "SRP"
  .Range("AA1").Value = "CaptionIncluded"
  .Range("AB1").Value = "Caption Required"
  .Range("AC1").Value = "Any"
  .Range("AD1").Value = "Total Run Time (minutes)"
  .Range("AE1").Value = "Total Run Time (mins.)"
End With
```

I know that there is a different and simpler way to write this code, since all of the values are on the same row, but different columns.  Does anybody know?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use array like this:

```
Sub sample2()

Dim myarray

myarray = Array("Display Name", "Language", "Locale", "WorkType", ... "Total Run Time (mins.)")

Range("A1", Cells(1, UBound(myarray) + 1)).Value = myarray

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow you're able to test it that fast. awesome!. glad it worked for you.